# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type com.example.simpleapplocker.Users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[firbase data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS3gz.png)

i want to fetch firebase date to recycle view so i get value of userSnapshot to Users.class it shows error please help me i have seen error "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.*** "
but i have error of Boolean

here it shows error

```
DatabaseReference userref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Connection").child("User");
        userref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Users users = userSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                        usersList.add(users);

                    }
                    mAdapter = new Adapter_All_Users(usersList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                }

            }
}
```

Users class is just a simple class

```
package com.example.simpleapplocker;

public class Users {
    private String Name;
    private String Email;
    private String Location;
    private String Age;
    private String Sex;

    public Users() {


    }

    public Users(String Name, String Email, String Location, String Age, String Sex) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Location = Location;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.Sex = Sex;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return Sex;
    }
}
```

don't know whats the issue

Comment: If you look in the Firebase console, is there some true/false value in a place you don't expect?

Comment: No there's not any true/value  there are 5 values that all are stored  as string

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the data in Firebase?

Comment: @cricket_007  here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS3gz.png

Comment: Got the error there was a ID in database where  name, email, age, location were not defined

Comment: @MuhammadOwaisChaudhary You say you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes it's solved